# Cannot access Drupal Admin panel after migration - login expires right after logged in

Tags: php, drupal, admin

I have migrated live Drupal website from localhost for development purposes. Installed everything correctly but I cannot access admin panel when I logged it, it accepts the password and directs me to user profile ben when I navigate to admin panel it says " Access denied. You may need to login below or register to access this page. " . I believe when I click any link on the page the session expires. How can i fix the problem?

Comment: If it's Drupal 6 make sure you have an anonymous user record in the `users` table (uid of 0). It usually doesn't copy across properly

Answer (score 0):

Check that apache mod_rewrite module is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have find out, I have to set `$cookie_domain = 'mydomain.com';` at settings.php. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Drupal 6, make sure the hash function is set to MD5. I had the same issue when the php setting 'session.hash_function' was set to sha512.

You can try changing the hash function in your Drupal settings file:

```
ini_set('session.hash_function', '0');
```

This changes it to MD5. (http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function)